# how to configure saml2 token profile on wso2 carbon sts

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, rampart

Is there a way to configure the wso2carbon-sts to work with the saml token profile, instead of the username token profile?

in other words I want to login with the sts by passing a saml2 token, instead of a username and password.

I don't want to use in the ws security header the tag UsernameToken, but something like SecurityTokenReference

I tried modifying some ws policies in the service meta file, and also from the back end gui, but it didn't work.

I'd like to have an hello world for this scenario, does it exists?